# Syntax error in csv.writer

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I getting a syntax error and I need some help please?
I tried to solve the problem, but I couldn't.

Here is the code with error:

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import *


light1 = pd.read_csv('G:/light1.csv')

light1.Time = pd.to_datetime(light1.Time)

tdelta = datetime.timedelta(hours=5)
time_before_5_hours  = light1.Time + tdelta
#rng = pd.date_range(start=light1.Time, end=time_before_5_hours,periods=1, freq='m' )
s = light1.Time
m= light1.Time - DateOffset(hours = 5)


from dateutil import rrule
import datetime
def hours_between(start_date, end_date):
    time = rrule.rrule(rrule.MINUTELY, dtstart=s, until=m)
    return hours_between
with open('G:/project/light1.csv') as input_file:
    with open('G:/light2.csv', 'w') as csvoutput:
        writer = csv.writer(csvoutput, lineterminator='\n')
        reader = csv.reader(input_file)

        all = [ ]
        row = next(reader)
        row.append('k')
        all.append(row)

        for row[0] in csv.reader(input_file):
            try:
                v = hours_between(input_file.Time,input_file.Time - DateOffset(hours = 5))
                if v.bool() == True :
                    row.append(1)
                    all.append(row)
                    writer.writerows(all)
                    row = next(reader)
                else:
                    row.append(0)
                    all.append(row)
            writer.writerows(all)
```

Error:

```
 File "<ipython-input-139-aa2b4e5dbb1e>", line 41
    writer.writerows(all)
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: the error in writer

Comment: The only thing valid at that point in the code would be an `except:` or `finally:` clause to go with the previous `try:` at that indentation level.

Comment: The name `all` is used by a built-in function. Try using a different name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In python each `try:` statement has to be closed with an `except:` or `finally:` statement. `except` dictates what to do if whats inside the try clause threw an error, and `finally` determines what to do immediately after the `try:` clause has been ran. You don't have a closing statement for your `try`. If you want to just ignore any exceptions from your code you can just do this:

```
try:
    v = hours_between(input_file.Time,input_file.Time - DateOffset(hours = 5))
    if v.bool() == True :
        row.append(1)
        all.append(row)
        writer.writerows(all)
        row = next(reader)
    else:
        row.append(0)
        all.append(row)
    writer.writerows(all)

except:
    pass
```

Comment: Not necessarily an `except`, but at least one of `else`, `except`, or `finally`. For example, `try...finally...` is a common idiom for when you don't really care if there was an error or not, as long as something gets done after the attempt and before proceeding (whether to the next statement or up the call stack with the exception).

Comment: @chepner noted and edited. However a try cannot be closed by an  else without an except

Comment: You're right; I could have sworn I'd done that once upon a time, though.